# Can't extend root partition using gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm new to Ubuntu. I've allocated 110 GB to my root partition and I have 315 GB unallocated space and I'm trying to extend my root partition to include the excess 315 GB. I have searched for other methods but i can't understand the process because I have missing partitions like linux-swap and the extend partition.

[image: My disk management picture in GParted]

And also i tried unlocking my ext4 partition but it said

> currently in use disk is busy

How can I extend my root partition to use the unallocated space to its left?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `free -h`, `sudo blkid`, and `cat /etc/fstab`. Please also explain how your disk partitions got to look like this. Had you been deleting partitions? Does Ubuntu run properly? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema i did all the commands that you said and this the output. 

$ free -h 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           9.7G        1.9G        6.0G        344M        1.8G        7.2G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G

Comment: Umm, i deleted some partitions. but it was windows 10 partitions, initially i install ubuntu dual boot with windows 10. then afterwards i deleted win10 and i just followed the instrustions in youtube and not knowing that the swap partition is need for this kind of issue. any tips for me to do to properly or should i just reformat it with ubuntu again? if so can you suggest a proper partitioning of disk? @heynnema

Comment: Just go ahead and follow my answer, below. It looks like you've created a 2G swapfile, so you don't need a swap partition. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- right-click on /dev/sda9 and select `move`
- `move` the entire /dev/sda9 partition all the way to the left
- `resize` the right side of /dev/sda9 all the way to the right
- click the Apply checkmark

Reboot the computer.

Comment: +1 but OP seems not to have a swap partition, possibly because they have a swap file instead? They seem confused about that, so maybe you could add some hints about it

Comment: @Zanna you may be right. OP is confused, and has probably deleted a few partitions... as they only show sda7/8/9. I've left a new comment for OP, but they haven't responded to anybody since 11/26/18. I'll amend my answer if they do. Thanks!